# Add directory containing pre compiled module in CMakeLists

Tags: compilation, linker, cmake, fortran

I am modifying a CMakeLists.txt file for a fortran code. I need to add a directory that contains a precompiled module.
How can I do that in CMakeLists.txt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a target property called [Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY.html)

For good measure, I also add the module directory as an include directory. `gfortran` looks for `.mod` files in the include directories.

```
set_target_properties( Target PROPERTIES Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY "dir" )
target_include_directories(Target PUBLIC "dir" )
```

**Edit**

Reading through your question again, I see that the module you are interested in is already compiled. `Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY` specifies where to PUT `.mod` files, and adds that directory as a place to look for them. `target_include_directories` statement just specifies where to look for them.  I am most familiar with using `gfortran`, which has this in it's man page:

```
  -Idir
       These affect interpretation of the "INCLUDE" directive (as well as of the "#include" directive of the
       cpp preprocessor).

       Also note that the general behavior of -I and "INCLUDE" is pretty much the same as of -I with
       "#include" in the cpp preprocessor, with regard to looking for header.gcc files and other such things.

       This path is also used to search for .mod files when previously compiled modules are required by a
       "USE" statement.

   -Jdir
       This option specifies where to put .mod files for compiled modules.  It is also added to the list of
       directories to searched by an "USE" statement.

       The default is the current directory.
```

This is what CMake will do for you and your compiler; you shouldn't need to specify these flags explicitly. In your case, just the includes should be sufficient, since the module has already been compiled.

However, if you find it's not working with your compiler, you may have to specify them manually by setting the variable CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: set_target_properties halts compilation of other modules, so I just put target_include_directories, but I dont know what I am doing. And do I need to add something  to SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES ?